# Visual Studio not Recognising IDisposable Type

Tags: c#, smtp

I have the following `Email` class which contains 1 method `Send`:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

static class Email
{
    const string EmailAddress = "JoeBloggs@domain.com";
    const string Subject = "Error Detected in Application";

    public static void Send(string body)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient("mail.mailserevrname.com", 25)
            { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(), EnableSsl = false })
        {
            client.Send(EmailAddress,
                        EmailAddress,
                        Subject,
                        body);
        }
    }
}
```

I have used this code in multiple applications and I have never had a problem with it (no errors, the email gets sent as/when expected).

However, in my current project, when I copy the class in, I am seeing this error:

> 'SmtpClient': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

I have never seen this error being produced by the above code. We can also see from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) that `SmtpClient` does implement `IDisposable`:

`public class SmtpClient : IDisposable`

Does anyone know why this error is appearing now and not in my other applications? Or does anyone know where a good starting point would be to investigate this?

Comment: Freely assuming that you're not targeting .NET 3.5 or anything like that?

Comment: @J.Steen I am targeting 3.5... I guess it doesn't inherit `Dispose` in that framework version

Comment: Nope, it sure doesn't.

Comment: @J.Steen Ah thanks for the pointer! Maybe I will try and extend `SmtpClient` with a `Dispose` method

Comment: As for your last question: a good starting point is always to look at the different framework versions of an implementation. =)

Comment: I think that NetworkCredential not implement IDisposable Interface, declare your credential before using statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @J.Steen's comment pointed out, in .NET Framework 3.5, `SmtpClient` does not implement `IDisposable`.

As a result, the solution is to create a class which inherits from `SmtpClient` and implements `IDisposable` and use that in the `using`.

EDIT:

```
class Mailer: SmtpClient, IDisposable {
    //...
}
```

Is the way to implement `IDisposable` and inherit from `SmtpClient`

Comment: Hi Lajos thanks for your answer. I am trying to do this now but I can't work out where to start! I want to write something like `Mailer : SmtpClient : IDisposable`, but C# does not support multiple inheritance! Do you have any advice you can share?

Comment: I actually think I have worked it out - will post some code here shortly

Comment: @Bassie, I have edited my answer to give you an example to do it.

Comment: must be `class Mailer: SmtpClient, IDisposable` since you can implement multiple interfaces